# Creating an intersecting linestring layer from two polygon layers using some tolerance

Tags: qgis, postgis, spatial-analyst, intersection

I have two postgis layers:

- The first layer contains the sidewalks of my town (polygons in blue).
- The second one contains the pavements (roads) of my town (polygons in brown).

The map looks like this in QGIS with both layers activated:

[image]

Ok, now I have to obtain a layer with the curbs (lines) in the town starting from these two layers. The new layer must be composed of linestrings. Each element in this new layer should be a linestring where every of the greometries of the two layers intersect.

In the following snapshot I manually painted the geometries that should be created in this particual area:

[image]

Sorry about my bad pulse. I hope it helps to understand me better.

Ok, if I just add the layers to QGIS, for example, and intersect one layer with another I get the following layer:

[image]

The new green layer is the obtained curbs layer. I have two snags with this layer:

- It is composed of polygons
- Not all the curvs are drawn.

With this last evidence I discover that the sidewalks and roads layers were not precisely delineated one next to the other, so I need some kind of tolerance in the operation to get the layer I am looking for. As I told before it should be a linestring layer.

I don't mind if the query is directly done in postgis or using QGIS or other software's tools, I just can't figure out right now how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

In PostGIS you can use [ST_Buffer](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) to add a little margin to one of the polygon layers, then use [ST_Intersection](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html) to get the curbs polygon. <s>Now the [ST_StraightSkeleton](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_StraightSkeleton.html) may give you what you want (haven't actually tested but it should work).</s>

As noted below skeletonize produces wrong result. The better way should be to do `ST_DumpRings` on the roads polygon and get `ST_Intersection` of rings and the curb polygon.

Comment: Hi @Jakub Kania thanks for your post. If I use straight skeleton I obtain a multilinestring layer with some kind of perpendicular lines that i don't want.. Please see next snapshot: http://imgur.com/AhXx5xs

Comment: @Egidi Yes, skeletonize was probably an overkill. I edited with a suggestion but I don't really have time right now to prepare a proper answer, I'll try to get back to it.